# Add a join to a complex SQL query

Tags: sql, join

I have an existing SQL query and I need to add a join to it so the results of this query only get returned if the value of a column in another table is the same as what the join specifies. I have done joins in the past but they were always on simpler queries. I am just not sure where to insert the join, everything I have tried has syntax problems. In English I want:

EXISTING QUERY...JOIN ON ANOTHER TABLE WHERE ANOTHERTABLE.COLUMNNAME = "SOMEVALUE"

The query is:

```
    ; WITH cte_DateFormat AS (SELECT        ServerName, CONVERT(DATE, Date, 103) AS Date, [Capacity(GB)], [Free Space (GB)], Region
                                                           FROM            [Some_Table]), cte_Rank AS
    (SELECT        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ServerName, CAST(YEAR(Date) AS VARCHAR(4)) + CAST(MONTH(Date) AS VARCHAR(2))
      ORDER BY Date DESC) AS ID, Region, ServerName, Date, [Capacity (GB)], [Free Space (GB)]
FROM            cte_DateFormat)
    SELECT        Region, ServerName, Date, [Capacity (GB)], [Free Space (GB)]
     FROM            cte_Rank
     WHERE        ID = 1
     ORDER BY Date DESC, Region DESC
```

Comment: can you use sqlfiddle to place your example table?

Comment: you want to join on which column of table `cte_rank`?

Comment: join with column "ServerName"

Comment: both cte_DateFormat and cte_Rank are CTEs. You can join to either as if they were tables.

Comment: have a look here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Still not sure how to implement the join. The result set of this query contains two categories of data. To separate them out I need to join to another table that has another column that differentiates the data in the result set

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you don't want to join, you want to ask for the existence of a value in another table. So use EXISTS:

```
; WITH cte_DateFormat AS (...) , cte_Rank AS (...)
SELECT Region, ServerName, Date, [Capacity (GB)], [Free Space (GB)]
FROM cte_Rank
WHERE ID = 1
AND EXISTS
(
  select * 
  from anothertable 
  where anothertable.servername = cte_Rank.ServerName 
  and ... -- some other criteria if needed
)
ORDER BY Date DESC, Region DESC
```